# Find the volume of the solid enclosed by the paraboloids

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid enclosed by the paraboloids $z=16-3x^2-3y^2$
and $z=4$ so what i did is this $4=16-3x^2-3y^2$ and I'm not sure about the following steps.

Comment: By setting the two given constraints to be true, all you are doing is asserting that the point $(x, y, z)$ exists in the intersection between the two regions. Think about what you are doing, and how it differs from what the question is asking.

Answer (score 2):

$4 = 16 - 3x^2 - 3y^2 \to x^2 + y^2 = 2^2$, this tells you about the base disk that you integrate on. Using cylindrical coordinates: $x = r\cos\theta$, $y = r\sin\theta$, $z = z$, we have: $V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^2\int_{4}^{16-3r^2} rdzdrd\theta$

Answer (score 1):

Region in the plane $xy$:
$$
4 = 16 - 3x^2 - 3y^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x^2 + y^2 = 4 \quad \Rightarrow \quad r = 2
$$
Using polar coordinates, we have
$$
V = \int_R\int f(x,y)dA = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}(16 - 3r^2)rdrd\theta = 2\pi \int_{0}^{2}(16r - 3r^2)dr = 48\pi
$$

Answer (score 1):

As you see, I just wanted to illustrate what other post tried to indicate mathematically:

[image]

[image]

[image]